# Multithreading design

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a program that will store some network activity data from some servers. For the speed I will design the application to make each request in a separate thread and put the result in a generic dictionary where the key is the server id and the object is the result class.

However this responses from the server should be saved each 10 minutes to DB. I don't know if I have any good idea how to solve this. So some input would be great.

What I have in mind is to lock the result dictionary and make a deep clone of the result and start to analyze the result in another thread that just put it in the DB.

How could I minimize the blocking from the `request threads` so they can start to add fresh results asap but still read from the dictionary?

Comment: Just swap the dictionary with a new one.  Very fast, don't forget to lock.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to take the current state aside in the time your persist logic fires while directing new input into a fresh storage. This is the basic pattern for this task:

```
class PeriodicPersist{

    // Map must be volatile, persist may look at a stale copy
    private volatile Map<String, String> keyToResultMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public  void newResult(String key, String result) {
        synchronized(keyToResultMap) {  // Will not enter if in the beginning of persist
            keyToResultMap.put(key,result);
        }
    }

    public void persist(){
        Map<String, String> tempMap;
        synchronized (keyToResultMap) { // will not enter if a new result is being added just now.
            if(keyToResultMap.size() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            tempMap = keyToResultMap;
            keyToResultMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }

        // download freshMap to the DB OUTSIDE the lock
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid dealing with locking the dictionary by using the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). Run a thread every 10 mins using Timer based events that will check the contents of the Dictionary and save current count items to your DB, remove the same and then start the analysis on the saved content.

```
// myCD is your concurrent dictionary
// every 10 mins
var myCDClone = myCD.MemberwiseClone();
// save to DB using myCDClone 
// using myCDClone.Keys delete everything saved up from myCD
// myCDClone.Clear();
```

Comment: Is it possible to clone it even if there is a none thread safe list as the object inside of the CD? ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, List<T>> what if the list is modified in the same moment?

Comment: No the concurrency due not percolate down to all keyvaluepair objects,  just the dictionary access.